# jQuery Accordion - How to form the h1 heading to an link

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI. I created my problem at jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kAyT4/1/

My Problem: It is no problem to klick on "Section 1" and on the different links in the div container. But I directly want to link the h1 header "Go directly to google"! How can I combine it with my iFrame?

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>  
      <a href="http:/www.google.de" target="iframe">Google</a>                   
  </div>
  <h3>Go directly to google</h3>  
</div>
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An accordion header can't link to a page.

Maybe this helps you:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-accordion-header-act-as-a-link-to-a-page